# How does the Hardware Expert aced skill work, especially with drills?

Tags: payday-2

> HARDWARE EXPERT
>
> ACE
>
> Gives drill a small chance to **autorestart** when it breaks down.
>   [...] 30% chance for drill to **autorestart**.

What do they mean with *autorestart* ?  One of our teammates aced the skill and didn't see any difference while interacting with the drill.  Is there any distance to maintain between the drill and the tech guy in order to make this skill work ?

Comment: I've seen it happen only once with a friend who has the perk aswell, as the drill broke down he ran towards it to fix and right when he was close to it !poof! it started back up.

Comment: Ok :(  it sounds handy but the random part without any indicator (just as @Hex said) makes it so worthless...

Comment: Well it depends, for all you know you are doing the bank heist, and you are pinned down trying to fight off the waves of police entering the bank, then before you know it the drill breaks down and right before you start screaming at your screen it magicaly starts back up... I would be happy for that :p

Comment: Point taken !  Simply sad it's so "random" (without any indication)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual effect of the skill is:

> If a drill breaks down it has a 30% chance to automatically restart after a few seconds.

[Source](http://denkirson.proboards.com/thread/6425)

The main issue with this is that you will in most cases run to the drill and start repairing it anyway, before you know if the auto-repair triggers.

Comment: Is it just me or is it completely worthless then ?

Comment: @Anto Well yeah, as long as you have someone guarding the drill it won't make any real difference. At best it's a situational skill for when you need to spend a lot of time fighting in other areas.

Answer (score 1):

> **Whether a drill auto-restarts or not is decided when placing or
>   upgrading it**. **There is a 30% chance that the drill becomes an
>   auto-restarter** and always restarts 5-20 seconds after jamming.
>   Otherwise the drill does not benefit at all. **Auto-restarters may jam
>   several times, but will always fix themselves until they are finished.**
>   Upgrading or repairing a drill does confer the chance only if the
>   auto-restart icon is not shown already (which itself does not indicate
>   whether the drill is an auto-restarter or not). **Thus you always have
>   exactly one chance for the drill to be an auto-restarter. If it is
>   not, it will never be.**

<sup>Source: [The Long Guide - Remarks on Technician Skills](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=267214370#309672) by Frankelstner (emphasis mine) (info are taken from extracted game files)</sup>

> All drills have a 30% chance of being auto-restarters with the skill. That means that if it restarts once, it will always restart itself after a while. There's no way of telling if a drill is an auto-restarter, besides waiting and checking if it restarts or not.
>
> ---
>
> Auto restarters are coded to restart after 5+rand*15 seconds, or 5-20 seconds, if they successfully got the trait. If it doesn't restart automatically after 20 seconds, it never will.
>
> ---
>
> ... If [the drill] won't restart, you'll usually get some kind of audio queue from a heister telling you to fix the drill if it's been long enough.

<sup>Source: [Related posts on Reddit /r/paydaytheheist](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2crx47/how_can_you_tell_if_a_drill_youve_placed_has/) by users [Menolith](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2crx47/how_can_you_tell_if_a_drill_youve_placed_has/cjidzux), [KarateF22](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2crx47/how_can_you_tell_if_a_drill_youve_placed_has/cjina3x) and [Shadeol](http://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/2crx47/how_can_you_tell_if_a_drill_youve_placed_has/cjif8c1), supporting the information quoted from the Long Guide above</sup>
The HUD mod, [HoxHud](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/HoxHud) (PC only) can give an indication whether a placed drill has an auto-restart chance. Without a mod, as mentioned above, there's no way of telling if a drill is an auto-restarter, besides waiting and checking if it restarts or not.

Answer (score 0):

The drill will have a small chance to automatically fix itself after a few seconds of being jammed. This can be useful if the drill jams and you're far away from it.

[image: Gives drill a 30% chance to autorestart when it breaks down]